# google analytics APIをpythonで利用する

Tags: python, google-analytics-api

上記について、下記のURLの通りにやっているのですが、
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/service-py

下記のエラーが出ます。解決方法をご存知のかた、宜しくお願い致します。

```
C:\Users\Documents>python HelloAnalytics.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "HelloAnalytics.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apiclient.discovery import build
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\tensorenv\lib\site-packages\apiclient\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from googleapiclient import channel
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\tensorenv\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\channel.py", line 62, in <module>
    from googleapiclient import errors
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\tensorenv\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\errors.py", line 25, in <module>
    from oauth2client import util
ImportError: cannot import name 'util'
```

---

#### 追記

`pip show google-api-client`の結果：

```
Name: google-api-python-client
Version: 1.3.2
Summary: Google API Client Library for Python
Home-page: http~
Author: Google Inc.
Author-email: UNKNOWN
License: Apache 2.0
Location: c:\users\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages
Requires: uritemplate, httplib2, oauth2client
```

`pip show oauth2client`の結果：

```
Name: oauth2client
Version: 4.0.0
Summary: OAuth 2.0 client library
Home-page: http~
Author: Google Inc.
Author-email: UNKNOWN
License: Apache 2.0
Location: c:\users\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages
Requires: pyasn1, six, rsa, httplib2, pyasn1-modules
```

Comment: `pip show google-api-python-client`と`pip show oauth2client`の結果を追記してくださいませんか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。できれば質問本文を編集してくださると嬉しいです（コメントは後からこの質問を見に来た方からは見づらいためです）。編集は質問の下の「編集」リンクから行えます。

Comment: もしかしてgoogle-api-python-clientのインストールは`conda install`経由でしょうか？

Comment: いえ、直接コマンドプロンプトからpipしました。

Comment: なるほど。その際`--upgrade`オプションは付けましたか？

Comment: いえ、pip install -I google-api-python-client==1.3.2で行いました。

Comment: 古いバージョンが必要なのでしょうか。でしたら[この質問](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40708563/google-drive-api-importerror-cannot-import-name-util)と状況が同じですので、`pip install oauth2client==2.2.0`で解決するかと思います。

Comment: すいません、--upgradeで解決できました。大変失礼いたしました。ありがとうございます。

Comment: より詳しい回答を投稿しましたので、もしよろしければ[回答を承認](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)していただけると嬉しいです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`google-api-python-client`のバージョンと`oauth2client`のバージョンが不整合を起こしています。特に、古いバージョンの`google-api-python-client`だと新しいバージョンの`oauth2client`に対応していません。

古いバージョンに拘らないのであれば、どちらのパッケージも最新のものにすると良いでしょう。たとえばpipを使っているなら `pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client` が使えます。

古いバージョンが必要ならそれ用の`oauth2client`が必要です。今回は`google-api-python-client`のバージョンが1.3.2とのことなので、`oauth2client`のバージョンをたとえば2.2.0にすると解決すると思います ([参考](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40708563/google-drive-api-importerror-cannot-import-name-util))。

具体的にどのバージョンが必要なのかは、たとえば、`google-api-python-cliend` v1.5.0 以降でしたら (※1)、GitHub上の[リリースタグ](https://github.com/google/google-api-python-client/releases)からそのバージョンを見つけ、そのコミットにおける[`setup.py`](https://github.com/google/google-api-python-client/blob/master/setup.py)で`oauth2client`のバージョンがどう指定されているかを見ればよいです。現在最新版のv1.6.2だと`'oauth2client>=1.5.0,<5.0.0dev'`が要求されています。

※1. より正確には[このプルリク](https://github.com/google/google-api-python-client/pull/184)以降でしたら

Comment: ご対応ありがとうございました。